# Laravel: How to use Artisan Facade to call terminal commands in Controllers & Models

Tags: laravel, namespaces, command, laravel-artisan, facade

I have the following 'artisan' command set up

```
protected $signature = 'make:sub {type} {name}';
```

The above command works when typed into the terminal.

I want to call it dynamically in a controller. Below is my code:

```
    $name = $request->input("name");

    Artisan::call('make:sub', [
        'type' => 'origin', 'name' => $name
    ]);
```

The above is not working.

I think the issue might be the 'artisan namespace'.

What is the correct 'use namespace' to call artisan commands set up in the command folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got 2 options.

1) at the beginning of the file, you can type: `use Artisan;`

2) just type :

```
\Artisan::call('make:sub', [
     'type' => 'origin', 'name' => $name
]);
```